# Bash script convert "string" to number

Tags: linux, bash, script

i need to change a string to interger, because i check the size of file (extract with : stat -c%s $filename) with a number, follow the complete script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable that contain path destination file
path=/sobstitude

# Variable for size
size=1000

# Loop for file scan
for filename in /test/*;
do
    # Take the size of file
    filesize=$(stat -c%s $filename)

# Check if the file is empty
if [ $filesize > $size ]
then

    # Replace file
    mv $filename $path

fi
done

exit 0;
```

Comment: Instead of checking the file size in the script, you can use `find` with `-size` to only list files that are in the adequate size bracket, and since you can tell find to execute a command against matching files, your whole script becomes `find /test/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1000c -exec mv {} /sobstitude \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i've solved after change this :

```
if ((filesize > size))
```

Now work, thanks for support

Answer (score 1):

No need to "convert" data types. You can use `-gt` or `-lt` to compare numbers:

```bsh
➜ size="$(stat -c%s test.mp4)"; [[ "$size" -gt 4000 ]] && echo "bigger" || echo "smaller"
bigger

➜ size="$(stat -c%s test.mp4)"; [[ "$size" -gt 400000 ]] && echo "bigger" || echo "smaller"
smaller
```

The `>` is not wrong in principle. You can use [arithmetic expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) to perform the comparison.

I've used `[[` in place of `[` for its [extended features](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/5893).

Note that all variable expansions should be double-quoted. Particularly with `$filename` and `$path`, if any of those contain whitespace, your script will fail.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`/`sh` variables contain strings, there is no strict concept of integers. A string may look like an integer and it's enough.

`stat -c%s $filename` should return a string that looks like an integer.

In your case the main problem is in the redirection operator `>` (you probably now have files with names that are numbers in the working directory). This snippet:

```
[ $filesize > $size ]
```

should be

```
[ "$filesize" -gt "$size" ]
```

And [use double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).